# Data transfer from PC to FPGA

Tags: usb, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I Have a simple function in FPGA ( like an adder ) but I want to this adder get the inputs from **PC** from  ( Quartus II ) 
for example I want to add two 12 bit number but I haven't enough switches .
How get input from pc and send them to FPGA and How get them in FPGA ?
(I just have USB Blaster Cable )

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using the USB Blaster, you could use the in-system sources and probes feature.  That will allow communication to and from the FPGA through the USB Blaster.

[ISSP](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.1/mergedProjects/program/stip/stip_about_stip.htm)